# How can I retrieve values and keys from a HashMap in Java 8?

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I tried to use an Iterator but Iterator.next() gives me an int. Not sure what to do with an int. How can I get the keys and values?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you trying to iterate over the keys and get the values? Just iterate over the values?

Comment: Either one. Keys or values. Iterator.next() returns an int. what am I supposed to do with the int?

Comment: Assuming you have `Map map = ...`, You can stream the keys using `map.keySet().stream()`. For the values `map.values().stream()`. `map.entrySet().stream` will give you a stream of `Map.Entry`

Comment: What is .stream() actually giving me?

Comment: A [`Stream<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : hashmap.entrySet()) {
       final String key = entry.getKey();
       System.out.println("Key:" + key);
       Object obj = entry.getValue();
}
```